# scale images using jquery animate method

Tags: jquery, image-scaling

I want to scale images using jquery as css3 transform doing.
so i wrote a script here it is

```
 (function(){
    $('.img_container img').on('mouseover',function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            width = $this.attr('width'),
            height = $this.attr('height'),
            new_width = (width + 10)+'px',
            new_height = (height + 10)+'px';

        $this.animate({'width':new_width,
                       'height':new_height,
                       'top':'-10px',
                       'left':'-10px'},{
                           duration:300,
                           });
        });
    })();
```

mouse over on the images increases there width and height more than 10px and unusually
any help please

i able to write another script.

```
(function(){
    var factor = 15;

$('.img_container img').on('mouseover',function(){

        var $this = $(this),
        height = $this.height(),
        width = $this.width();
    $(this).animate({
        top:  height - factor,
        left:  width - factor,
        width: width + factor,
        height: height +factor
    },200);
});
$('.img_container img').on('mouseleave',function(){

        var $this = $(this),
        height = $this.height(),
        width = $this.width();
    $(this).animate({
        top:  height + factor,
        left:  width + factor,
        width: width - factor,
        height: height - factor
    },200);
});

})();
```

However, if i move the mouse in and out of the image several times
really fast, the image will "throb" because it catches each event and
can't show them fast enough. It's like a delay of animation.how to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

```
var factor = 2;

$('.img_container img').on('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).animate({
        top: '-=' + $(this).height() / factor,
        left: '-=' + $(this).width() / factor,
        width: $(this).width() * factor
    });
});
```

for specific factor, refer this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xhchp/3/)

Comment: @samthush Then accept and give REP to his answer mate :]  I did it as I found this solution good.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be using

```
$(this).animate
```

instead of

```
$this.animate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
    $('.img_container img').on('mouseover',function(){
       var
            width =  $(this).css('width'),
            height =  $(this).css('height'),
            new_width = (width + 10)+'px',
            new_height = (height + 10)+'px';

        $(this).animate({'width':new_width,
                       'height':new_height,
                       'top':'-10px',
                       'left':'-10px'},{
                           duration:300,
                           });
        });
    })();
```